# How to convert a space-separated file into an Excel file in Linux?

Tags: awk, sed, conversion, excel

I have a file which looks like this:

```
ID avedebv debv2019 ebv2018 gebv2018 number avecvlean
7063993 1.06109 0.5325 0.7420 1.5084 206 66.5962
7076247 1.67947 2.1066 2.8630 3.0629 460 67.6856
7076881 -0.236859 -2.6794 0.8820 1.9994 282 66.1557
7126254 -0.409945 -2.2293 0.5860 1.2695 133 66.0323
7178892 0.464492 -0.0859 1.2640 1.3655 327 66.3985
7179256 1.33735 2.2111 1.4730 1.0873 48 67.9671
7247048 0.875797 0.8434 1.5680 2.3221 86 67.8639
7247721 2.44818 3.8560 2.2590 3.7478 306 69.2416
7271572 2.54853 4.1963 2.5310 2.4604 268 68.9649
7271958 1.48163 2.1094 2.6480 2.4154 396 67.8631
7310883 2.07762 2.6693 0.5610 0.8019 164 69.8769
7339810 1.93014 2.7640 2.4130 2.0771 112 70.453
7362729 1.79878 2.5744 1.5900 2.6763 247 69.8597
7383443 1.20869 1.0631 0.6140 0.7587 229 69.4386
7384385 1.95598 1.2635 3.1930 2.1413 32 71.9848
7385021 3.01675 3.7090 1.3690 1.4910 22 71.2533
7385509 0.686986 -0.1679 0.1500 0.2087 81 69.8795
7392631 2.07126 4.0996 0.8400 1.6370 103 70.6173
```

I want to change its format into an Excel file, so I can work on this data in Excel. How can I convert it with Linux?

Comment: You can simply open the file with excel, select the `Data` tab, select `Text to Columns`, ensure the `Delimited` radio button is selected and press next, set the `Delimeters` to `Space`, and press `Finish`.  Then save as excel workbook

Comment: If doing this manually is an option, then maybe use libreoffice (calc) to import the file into columns then save in Excel format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace each space with a comma to turn it into a Comma Separated Value file, and save it with a XLS suffix; then you can read it in to Excel (which will read the comma separated value data and turn it into XLS format automagically), work with it, and save it.  Here's a one liner which uses sed to do the search-and-replace, then saves the data to CSV format with the XLS suffix, and Bob's yer uncle.

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g' filename > filename.xls
```

Comment: yes, or `tr ' ' , <filename > filename.xls`

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html is a man page for tr

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

command

```
awk '{gsub(" ",",",$0);print $0}' filename| sed "s/,$//g" >file.xls
```

output

```
awk '{gsub(" ",",",$0);print $0}' filename| sed "s/,$//g"

    ID,avedebv,debv2019,ebv2018,gebv2018,number,avecvlean
    7063993,1.06109,0.5325,0.7420,1.5084,206,66.5962
    7076247,1.67947,2.1066,2.8630,3.0629,460,67.6856
    7076881,-0.236859,-2.6794,0.8820,1.9994,282,66.1557
    7126254,-0.409945,-2.2293,0.5860,1.2695,133,66.0323
    7178892,0.464492,-0.0859,1.2640,1.3655,327,66.3985
    7179256,1.33735,2.2111,1.4730,1.0873,48,67.9671
    7247048,0.875797,0.8434,1.5680,2.3221,86,67.8639
    7247721,2.44818,3.8560,2.2590,3.7478,306,69.2416
    7271572,2.54853,4.1963,2.5310,2.4604,268,68.9649
    7271958,1.48163,2.1094,2.6480,2.4154,396,67.8631
    7310883,2.07762,2.6693,0.5610,0.8019,164,69.8769
    7339810,1.93014,2.7640,2.4130,2.0771,112,70.453
    7362729,1.79878,2.5744,1.5900,2.6763,247,69.8597
    7383443,1.20869,1.0631,0.6140,0.7587,229,69.4386
    7384385,1.95598,1.2635,3.1930,2.1413,32,71.9848
    7385021,3.01675,3.7090,1.3690,1.4910,22,71.2533
    7385509,0.686986,-0.1679,0.1500,0.2087,81,69.8795
    7392631,2.07126,4.0996,0.8400,1.6370,103,70.6173
```